# What connector type is this 3 pin connector

Tags: identification, connector

Can anyone help me identify this connector?

It is 3 pin wire-to-wire female connector, distance between center of the pins is 4.5mm, each whole is 4mm. One of the pin holes is square. Looks like some kind of molex connector.

[image]

Comment: This style is usually called "molex" although Molex is a manufacturer and today these are made by several suppliers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [JST EL connector](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eEL.pdf).

[image]

[image]

It doesn't seem possible to get them from my usual sources. However, they do appear to still be made, and you can buy them directly from JST [on their website](https://order.jst-mfg.com/InternetShop/app/index.php?series_code=59&select=s#showProductList), as long as you're willing to buy a lot of them. The one you have in particular is [ELR-03V](https://order.jst-mfg.com/InternetShop/app/index?back=2&product=46335100&jgcd=0&view=ProductDetail), which costs ¥35 (about $0.33 US with current exchange rates) each in quantities as low as 10. (for just the housing, contacts are a different story)

Its mating connector would be the [ELP-03V](https://order.jst-mfg.com/InternetShop/app/index?back=2&product=46300500&jgcd=0&view=ProductDetail), which apparently you can only buy in quantities of at least 500, for ¥4.20 (approx. US$0.04) each

The relevant contacts are about ¥7 (approx. US$0.07) each but there are too many variables (what size wire you want, in particular) for me to bother linking to individual contact pages on JST's shop.

Answer (score 1):

If it it's really 4.5mm pitch, it could be a JST ELR-03V

Comment: That's it ! Male 4.5mm 3 pin plug with key shell and clamp

Comment: They have stock in Isreal you might be able to get a couple samples and pins ordered separately https://eurochip-tech.com/index.aspx?electronic-components=ELR-03V

Answer (score 0):

This style is usually called "molex" although Molex is a manufacturer and today these are made by several suppliers.

Search for "3 pin molex" in your favorite search engine and you should see several options and suppliers if you are looking to source these.

Comment: I did a search and the results that I get are for 4 pin molex connector with one of the pins removed or 4 pin molex to 3 pin fan connector. That why I posted a question here. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Molex Mini-fit jr 3 pin. But it isn't, since those pins aren't round.

They can be mate-n-lok, but also one of many copies.